# Is it possible at the same time to give all users of website the same session?

Tags: php

Is it possible at the same time to give all users of website the same $_SESSION?

Comment: why on earth would you want to?

Comment: `echo "150"; // Will show 150 to all users`

Comment: technically yes, but it completely defeats the purpose of sessions, so there is going to be a better way of achieving what ever it is you think this approach is useful for.

Comment: @Dagon: I want to do following `if($_SESSION['new_posts'] + 60 > time()) echo "there are new posts in the forum!";` I don't want to use mysql for that.

Comment: @hey you should query the forum\user read table for this.

Comment: @hey: Mysql is made for that. Bastardizing sessions by doing what you're trying to do is just stupid.

Comment: @Dagon: I don't want to run mysql query every page, which would check if there are any new posts.

Comment: @hey, if you're not using a database, how are you storing posts?

Comment: @zzzzBov: of course I use database, but I just don't want to run this query every page for every user.

Comment: @hey: Well, you have to do something. Either put it in a database or put it in a file. Put it in memcached, even. This crazy global session idea is not possible, and it is not what sessions are for.

Comment: that's what the db is for, that's how every one else does it, so why would you not?

Comment: db queries are cheap. It's once you start adding multiple joins on different views in massive volumes that you start to get into speed issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to do following
>   if($_SESSION['new_posts'] + 60 >
>   time()) echo "there are new posts in
>   the forum!"; I don't want to use mysql
>   for that.

An easy and fast way

on every new post you do:

```
//will write an empty file or just update modification time
touch ('new_posts.txt');
```

And then:

```
if(filemtime('new_posts.txt') + 60 > time()) { ... }
```

Answer (score 7):

I have interpreted your question in the following way:

> Is it possible at the same time to give all users of a website the same [state]?

Yes, shared state is usually stored in a database, although state may also be stored in the local file system.

Using `$_SESSION` is meant to save state for a ***single*** user. If you abuse that tool, you will create an insecure system.

Comment: I was about to write something similar, to which I'd also mention using shared memory, e.g. with APC or Memcache

Answer (score 1):

Global sessions are not possible without opening your site up for a gigantic security hole.

Instead, let's look at what you want to do, which is grabbing data while avoiding a query every page.

1) Writing the value out to a file and then reading it every request is an option.  Sessions are stored in a file on the server by default, so it would have the same speed as a session.

2) Store it in a cache such as APC, Memcache, Redis.

Keep in mind these are cached values - you'll still have to update them regularly. You have to use either a cron job or have the client update them. But what do you do when the cache expires and tons of clients are trying to update the cache at once? This is called the dogpile effect and it's something to think about.

Or you could just simply write a SQL query and execute it every page and keep it simple. Why don't you want to do this? Have you profiled the code and determined that it's an actual issue? Worrying about this before it's a known problem is a waste of time.